# How to handle batch asynchronously from incoming request with single record

Tags: postgresql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, spring-webflux, batching

How to create single batch out from multiple incoming request and then insert into database. And after batch completion I want to respond back all the request either fail or success.
Using reactive spring and reactive postgress and snowflake, each request can be inset into db but how I can achieve 1000TPS.
Here database connection details is coming along with request and it might me more than 5 db connection need to create at runtime and then store in a pool to reuse.

Comment: any code examples?